# Restify JsonClient URL x Path

Tags: node.js, restify

When I create a `JsonClient` in node I do the following:

```
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
  url: 'https://www.domain.com:4321/api'
});
```

Once I've done that, I make calls like so:

```
client.post('/service/path', { });
```

Which seems right. I expect that the path called would be something like `https://www.domain.com:4321/api/service/path`. However, what is happening is that the client is throwing away the `/api` base path and calling `https://www.domain.com:4321/service/path`.

I don't get it - I'm inserting the client URL into a config file, so that I can change hosts without any hassle; Now that I need a base path, I need to change the code as well as the config.

Comment: Ha!  I just realized you never even asked a question. My folly in answering that which was never asked.

Comment: @headcode Really don't get this community anymore. You did answered, and I just forgot to accept it. I also did some due diligence and opened an issue on restify git, to which developers responded that, indeed, the behavior is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a wrapper around the restify JsonClient stuff you could do it with minimal code change and the config would, I think, work the way you want it.

Create a library file myClient.js

```
'use strict';
var restify = require('restify');
var jsonClient = null;

module.exports = {
    createJsonClient: function(opts){
        var opts = opts || {};
        var url = opts.url;
        var parts = url.split('/');
        var main_url = parts[0] + '//' + parts[2];
        var basePath = parts[3] ? parts[3] : '';
        jsonClient = restify.createJsonClient({url: main_url});

        return {
            get: function(path, cb){
                var adjusted_path = '/' + basePath + path;
                jsonClient.get(adjusted_path, function(err2, req2, res2, obj2){
                    return cb(err2, req2, res2, obj2);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this.

```
var myClientWrapper = require('./lib/myClient');
var client = myClientWrapper.createJsonClient({url: 'http://localhost:8000/api'});

client.get('/service/path/one', function(err, req, res, obj){
    if(err){
        console.log(err.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

It could use some more error checking and the url parsing is a little brittle, but it does work. I tried it out. Of course, I only wrapped the `get` function but you can see how it would work for the others.

Comment: Since this happens to every restify client, I created a generic wrapper and helper construction functions for every method.